# I'm trying to display a data from a Sqlite database in ListView but get Task List does not contain a public instance for GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I can connect to the database and with a breakpoint can view the returning data in the task call. In my Chambers.xaml.cs file I get the GetEnumerator error on the listchamber for this task while trying to use it in a Foreach routine to fill a binding variable for the ListView.

````
Chamber.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MrDiver.Views.Chambers"
             Title="Chambers"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MrDiver.Models"
             BackgroundColor="LightYellow"
             >
       
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="30"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        BackgroundColor="LightGrey"
        >

        <Label Text="DCI EMERGENCY England, Northern Ireland or Wales phone 07831 151523" ></Label>

        <Label Text="DCI EMERGENCY Scotland phone 0345 408 6008 " ></Label>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListChambers}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Model_Chambers">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Town}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Address}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Chamber.xaml.cs

```
using MrDiver.Data;
using MrDiver.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MrDiver.Views;
public partial class Chambers : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model_Chambers> ListChambers { get; set; } = new();
    public Chambers()   
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PortDatabase portDatabase = new PortDatabase();
        var listChambers = portDatabase.ChamberList();
        ListChambers.Clear();

            foreach (var model_Chambers in listChambers)
            {
                ListChambers.Add(model_Chambers);
            }

    }

}
```

PortDatabase.cs

```

using SQLite;
using MrDiver.Models;

namespace MrDiver.Data
{
    public class PortDatabase
    {
        private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

    public static string DBPath { get; } =
            Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Port.db3");

        public PortDatabase()
        {
            // _database is the connection to read the database
            _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DBPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache);
            // creates a new table named Coastguard if it doesn't exist
            _database.CreateTableAsync<Model_Chambers>();
            
        }
        public async Task<List<Model_Chambers>> ChamberList() 
        {
           var cham =  await _database.Table<Model_Chambers>().ToListAsync();
             return cham;
        }

    }
} 
```

Model_Chambers.cs

using SQLite;

namespace MrDiver.Models
{
    [Table("ChambersTable")]
    public class Model_Chambers
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        [Column("KEY")]
        public int Key { get; set; }

        [Column("NAME")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        [Column("ADDRESS")]
        public string? Address { get; set; }

        [Column("TOWN")]
        public string? Town { get; set; }

        [Column("COUNTY")]
        public string? County { get; set; }

        [Column("NATION")]
        public string? Nation { get; set; }

        [Column("TELEPHONE")]
        public string? Telephone { get; set; }
    }
}
````

I've tried all sort of variations of online examples including instead of Task<List> simply List but get a can not convert explicit Typeof error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listChambers`  is a `Task<List<Model_Chambers>>`. Tasks is a representation of something that will have a value in the future, so you need to wait until the value is available before being able to iterate over it. There are a few alternatives to do this:

1. Change `.ToListAsync()` to `.ToList()`, and adjust the return type to match.
2. Use `portDatabase.ChamberList().Result`. This should be functionally identical to option 1, but using `.Result` is frowned upon since there is a risk for deadlocks. I do not think these risks apply for this specific case, but it is something to be aware of.
3. Use use `var listChambers = await portDatabase.ChamberList()`. This require your method to be marked as async. As constructors cannot be marked as async you will need to move your code to a regular method. You will also need to consider how exceptions are handled, and that there might take some time for the list to be filled. So use try/catch, and consider a "loading..." label that is hidden once the actual data arrives.

If performance is not a concern I would go with option 1, just because it is simple. If the database call takes any noticeable amount of time option 3 would probably be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for your help and saving me tearing all my hair out. ToList() throws another error but .Result worked after I changed to a CollectionView and used a ChamberCollectionView.ItemsSource = ListChambers; to get the data into it.